# Querying XML Child Nodes with WHERE clause via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Is it possible to write a WHERE clause to select values from XML based on the value of a child node?

**Example XML**

```
<Message>
   <PrimaryKeyValue>12345</PrimaryKeyValue>
   <Events>
      <UpdatedDefaultAddress>True</UpdatedDefaultAddress>
      <UpdatedCustomerName>False</UpdatedCustomerName>
   </Events>
</Message>
<Message>
   <PrimaryKeyValue>67890</PrimaryKeyValue>
   <Events>
      <UpdatedDefaultAddress>False</UpdatedDefaultAddress>
      <UpdatedCustomerName>True</UpdatedCustomerName>
   </Events>
</Message>
```

**My Question**

How would I construct a query to only select PrimaryKeyValues where the value of `<UpdatedDefaultAddress>` is 'True'?

**My current code**

```
SELECT
t.c.value('(PrimaryKeyValue)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS PrimaryKeyValue
FROM @message_body.nodes('Message') as T(C)
WHERE t.c.exist('./Events/UpdateDefaultAddress') = 'True'
```

The problem with this is that I get both PrimaryKeyValues back in the result - I think the code is checking whether `<UpdatedDefaultAddress>` exists, rather than the value contained within it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.value()` instead of `.exists()`

```
DECLARE @message_body XML =N'<Message>
   <PrimaryKeyValue>12345</PrimaryKeyValue>
   <Events>
      <UpdatedDefaultAddress>True</UpdatedDefaultAddress>
      <UpdatedCustomerName>False</UpdatedCustomerName>
   </Events>
</Message>
<Message>
   <PrimaryKeyValue>67890</PrimaryKeyValue>
   <Events>
      <UpdatedDefaultAddress>False</UpdatedDefaultAddress>
      <UpdatedCustomerName>True</UpdatedCustomerName>
   </Events>
</Message>';

SELECT t.c.value('(PrimaryKeyValue)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS PrimaryKeyValue
FROM @message_body.nodes('Message') as T(C)
WHERE  t.c.value('(./Events/UpdatedDefaultAddress)[1]', 'varchar(10)')='True';
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ZMXIU1361)**